# Reading JSON file undefined (asynchronous)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Hello I'm trying to read a JSON file using nodejs and when I try to access one of the properties they come back as undefined. However, when I console.log the entire file is shows up.

```
var keyFile;

function setKeys(callback){
  const fs = require('fs');
  const filePath = '../KEY.json';
  fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8', (error, data) => {
    if (error){
      return console.log(error);
    }
    keyFile = data;
    callback();
  });
}

setKeys(()=>{
             console.log(keyFile) // shows JSON
             console.log(keyFile.google) //undefined
            });
```

KEY.json:

```
{
  "darksky": "ab",
  "google": "cd"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like you're parsing it anywhere. `data` will be a string, so change:

```
keyFile = data;
```

to

```
keyFile = JSON.parse(data);
```

---

Side note: Instead of using a module global, I'd strongly recommend passing the data to the callback as an argument:

```
// *** No var keyFile; here

function setKeys(callback){
  const fs = require('fs');
  const filePath = '../KEY.json';
  fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8', (error, data) => {
    if (error){
      return console.log(error);
    }
    callback(JSON.parse(data)); // ***
  });
}

setKeys(keyFile => {            // ***
  console.log(keyFile.google);
});
```

Comment: @Nigel: No worries. I should also have mentioned that you can read JSON via `require` if you like. For instance, this works: `const keyFile = requre("../KEY.json"); console.log(keyFile.google);` I don't recommend it, but you'll see people do it, so I figured I should flag it up.